# AWS S3 deny all access except for 1 user - bucket policy

Tags: security, amazon-s3, bucket

I have set up a bucket in AWS S3.  I granted access to the bucket for my IAM user with an ALLOW policy (Using the Bucket Policy Editor).  I was able to save files to the bucket with the user.  I have been working with the bucket for media serving before, so it seems the default action is to give public permission to view the files (images), which is fine for most web sites.

In my new project I want to be able to access the S3 bucket with an IAM user but want to deny all other access.  No public read access, no access whatsoever besides the IAM user who should have full access save/delete whatever.

What seems like I should do, I was reading about [here](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx14BCDOC9WO5R4/How-to-Create-a-Policy-That-Whitelists-Access-to-Sensitive-Amazon-S3-Buckets).  It says to create a `Deny` policy using the `NotPrincipal` attribute, and that way it will still allow that user, but deny everyone else.  For good measure I also added an `Allow` policy just for the user I want:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy**********",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt**********",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*********:user/my_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt*************",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::**********:user/my_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is denying access to everyone even `my_user`.  Again I can confirm that I had access when I just used the `Allow` portion of the policy above, but then the public also has read access, which I am trying to turn off.

How can I set up my bucket policy to give full access to only the unique IAM user and deny all access to any other user?

Thanks.

Comment: How, specifically, is "my_user" accessing the bucket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite simple:

- By default, buckets have **no public access**
- **Do NOT add a Bucket Policy**, since you do not want to grant access public access
- Instead, **add a policy to the IAM User** granting them access

The main thing to realise is that the IAM User cannot access content via unauthenticated URLS (eg `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.jpg`) because S3 doesn't know who they are. When the IAM User accesses the content, they will need to use **authenticated access** so that S3 knows who they are, such as:

- Accessing via the AWS Management Console using a Username + Password
- Accessing via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) using an Access Key + Secret Key

The policy on the IAM User would look something like:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is golden, thanks.  I will try that.  I noticed that adding both lines in the `Resource` was important.  I tried with that setup I have above and lost control of the bucket through the web interface...  So that was def not the right way.

Comment: I created a new bucket, gave no bucket policy and added the IAM policy like you have, and it works fine for that user.  But when I take the url for a photo and put it in my browser, I can access it that way as well.  That is what I was trying to turn off.  So it seems by default the whole bucket has public access.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: If an object is still publicly accessible via an anonymous URL, then check the object itself and make sure it does not have an "Everybody" permission defined. This is because permissions can be granted at the object, bucket OR user level. Also try it in another browser or an Incognito window in case something is cached. Oh, and don't use the "Actions->Open" command, because that generates a Pre-Signed URL that grants temporary access. Instead, click the blue link shown in the Properties pane, which is anonymous.

Comment: Thanks so much.  What is happening is what you suggested.  Each individual file DOES have an "Everybody" permission, where the bucket does not.  When I turn these off, those files then become private.  So it seems this is the issue.  Do you know how to set this behavior?  It seems to be giving this permission be default.

Comment: It is possible to grant PUBLIC-READ access (which means Everybody can view/download the object) at the time that the object is uploaded, so check how the files are getting into S3 and what options are being set.

Comment: Perfect.  That is what was happening.  I fixed my application to set the access level on the file when saving and now we are looking good!

Answer (score 1):

Get caller identity of the user

```bash
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Now, modify the `PrincipalArn` in the Policy Document below to put an exception.
Replace with your user/group/SSO user Arn here, you can also **match a pattern** like in the example below

```json
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::s3-test-bucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::s3-test-bucket/*"
           ],
           "Condition": {
               "StringNotEquals": {
                   "aws:PrincipalArn": ["arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_test_abcdef","**devops**"],
                   "aws:PrincipalServiceName": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

The above statement means the Deny Delete access to everyone except the SSO user, anything/anyone that has devops in it & AWS CloudTrail

Read [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html) on how multiple conditions apply in aws
Read this for the [types of conditional keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) you can use in aws

**Warning & Precaution:** If you are testing try with something like "Action": "s3:DeleteObject" instead of "*" . If you make a mistake while you put the policy everyone might loose access to the bucket. Only the Organisation root user will be then able to unblock the bucket.

Comment: Thats it. Worked very well. Thanks @Shivam Anand

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, allow access to buket only for 1 IAM user. We can use the bucket policy. I got this in netApp documnetation.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::95390887230002558202:federated-user/Bob"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::95390887230002558202:federated-user/Bob"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```